# Issue with gazebo plugin tutorial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys. I have been trying to do the gazebo plugin tutorial found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/GazeboPluginIntro). When i try to rosmake the package I created, it first indicate an error that gazebo.h is not found. I then replaced gazebo.h with gazebo.hh (i can only locate gazebo.hh in my system). That solved my issue, but it then gave me another error
" error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘GZ_REGISTER_PLUGIN’ with no type [-fpermissive]" during rosmake.

My cpp file is the same as what is  in the tutorial. Anyone here encountered this problem before?

In addition, may I know where can I learn to write and use a gazebo plugin? Since the ROS tutorial is "work in progress".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43310/issue-with-gazebo-plugin-tutorial/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2012-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

here are some examples of includes from my plugins:

```
#include "gazebo.hh"
#include "physics/physics.h"
#include "common/Events.hh"
#include "common/Plugin.hh"
#include "common/Time.hh"
#include "common/common.h"
```

As for the error maybe try putting ‘GZ_REGISTER_PLUGIN’ before the last '}' (outside the class, inside the namespace), that is how I have them declared.

[Here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/tutorials) are tutorials for the new gazebo.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [Andrei Haidu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1419/andrei-haidu/) with karma: 146 on 2012-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-09-07**:
Thanks Andrei.That solved my problem. However, I run into new [issue](http://answers.ros.org/question/43320/problems-with-gazebo-plugin-tutorials/) in Rosmake. I wonder if you faced similar problem?